# Django: How do I create separate instances of the same model object?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two classes that need to relate to each other.
an Item class and an Order class.

An Item object has several attributes: name, cost, quantity etc.
I want the **same item** to be able to belong to **several different Order objects** and white doing so, **having different attributes** inside that Order object. (Like different orders can have **different amounts** of the same Item on order)

Is this possible?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    order_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.description)

    @property
    def line_total(self):
        return self.cost * self.order_quantity


class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('issued', 'Issued'),
        ('closed', 'Closed'),
    )
    reference = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(
    Location, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                          choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                          default='draft')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('location',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.reference)
```

This setup allows me to have the same item in different orders, which is great, however I can't figure out how to make some Item attributes 'independent', based on which order they belong to.

Comment: Would the creation of an explizit ```through``` model as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) be an approach?

Comment: @Chris Thank you sir. It seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Chris down in the comments I've reached a solution that seems to work how I want it to.

I've added a third class

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
    Order, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    order_quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property 
    def line_total(self): <-----removed from Item class, pasted here
        return self.cost * self.order_quantity
```

I changed my Item class so it only contains attributes that shouldn't change

```
class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.description)
```

added **item_in_order** variable to my view:

```
def order(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.filter(reference=pk)
    items = Item.objects.filter(order=pk)
    item_in_order = Membership.objects.filter(order=pk)

    context = {'order': order, 'items': items,
           'item_in_order': item_in_order}
    return render(request, 'orderingapp/order.html', context)
```

and on the template:

```
<tbody>
    {% for item in item_in_order %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.item.description |title}}</td>
        <td>£{{item.cost |floatformat:2}}</td>
        <td>{{item.order_quantity |floatformat:0}}</td>
        <td>£{{item.line_total}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %} {% else %}
    <p>Nothing here</p>
    {% endif %}
</tbody>
```